# Why can't these generic types be inferred?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, type-inference

I have the following code:

```
public static class CardView {
    public static object Column<TModel, TResult>(Func<TModel, TResult> field) {
        return null;
    }
}

public class Person 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Gender { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var model = new Person() { Name = "Andre", Gender = true };

    var b = CardView.Column(model => model.Name); // ERROR
    // The type arguments for method 'UserQuery.CardView.Column<TModel,TResult>(System.Func<TModel,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
}
```

For some reason it's not able to infer the generic types for the `Column` method. I need to know why. I can't give up the type inference and specify the types myself because it's just a case study for a large problem where it will be indispensable.

**EDIT**

I misspelled the code =/ just fixed it

Comment: How do you expect it to infer `TModel`? The supplied lambda would be "valid" for *any* class that has a `Name` property.

Comment: Are you expecting the `.Column` method to determine you mean `m` to represent `model`?

Comment: Could you explain more in detail the reason to rely on type inference, just out of curiosity?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I think this is not the case, since you can say: `new List<Person>().Select(m => m.Name)` which will give you an `IEnumerable<string> without relying on the Person object.

Comment: Well, suppose *you* were given just the statement that you've called out as an error. How would *you* deduce what type arguments correspond to the type arguments? If you can't do it, how do you expect the compiler to do it?

Comment: @EricLippert, All I meant was that the issue has nothing to do with the `Person` type. It will be still the same issue for any other type, and the Linq example will work for any other type (suppose the lambda has valid code for the type used).

Comment: @IvayloSlavov: My comment was directed at the original poster, not at you. Regarding your response to Damien: You are incorrect. In your example the type inference engine has an additional fact, namely that the list is known to the compiler to be of type `List<Person>`. The type inference engine *does* rely on knowing the type of the collection elements when inferring the two type arguments for a call to Select.

Comment: @EricLippert, Sorry, I have misunderstood your comment. And as I happen to recently do this, I failed to be clear. My idea of the comment was that not having a property named `Name` is the issue, rather than the exact same knowledge for the complier what the type is. The Linq example has the knowlegde, and the code in the question does not.

Answer (score 7):

In order for the compiler to perform type inference it has to be given some sort of type information.  In this scenario the only information it's provided is an untyped lambda expression.  The compiler really has nothing to go on here.

There are a couple of ways to resolve this.  The easiest is to add a type to the lambda paramater

```
var b = CardView.Column((Person m) => m.Name);
```

Comment: In other words the complier cannot consider the type of the `m` variable as both the generic argument `TModel` of the method and the argument for the `Func`, right?

Comment: @IvayloSlavov no it could but what type does it have to go on? There are just no types to look at here.  Only 3 untyped items: method, lambda and lambda argument.

Comment: I meant, it has nothing to connect both of the type params to use the same type for them. If we had this code: `public static object Column<TModel, TResult>(Func<TModel, TResult> field)` and this call: `CardView.Column(m, p => p.Name);` the issue is no more. Of course, the code of `Column` should pass the first param to the lambda.

Answer (score 2):

The technical answer would be "because the specification doesn't say you can do that". Quoting [the spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx), section 7.5.2 (type inference):

> 7.5.2.1 The first phase
>
> For each of the method arguments Ei:
>
> 1. **If Ei is an anonymous function, an explicit parameter type inference
>      (§7.5.2.7) is made from Ei to Ti**
> 2. Otherwise, if Ei has a type U and xi
>      is a value parameter then a lower-bound inference is made from U to
>      Ti.
> 3. Otherwise, if Ei has a type U and xi is a ref or out parameter
>      then an exact inference is made from U to Ti.
> 4. **Otherwise, no inference is made for this argument.**

and:

> 7.5.2.7 Explicit parameter type inferences
>
> An explicit parameter type inference is made from an expression E to a type T in the following
>   way:
>
> - If E is an explicitly typed anonymous function with parameter types U1…Uk and T is a delegate type or expression tree type with parameter
>     types V1…Vk then for each Ui an exact inference (§7.5.2.8) is made
>     from Ui to the corresponding Vi.

Since the anonymous function in your example is not explicitly typed, no inference can be made. This also tells us that to have the inference made, you can help by specifying the type of the function:

```
var b = CardView.Column((Person m) => m.Name);
```

Now this is explicitly a `Func<Person, string>`, so inference is successful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `TModel` argument (or a generic type that uses `TModel`) in that method signature, so the compiler doesn't know the type of `m`.

Answer (score 0):

Your edited code won't compile.  You can't use `model` as the lambda parameter, because you already declared it as a local variable.  It appears that you want to tell the compiler that the lambda parameter is a `Person` by using an already-declared local of that type.  But that won't work.

The correct way to inform the compiler of the type is either to declare it explicitly in the lambda as others have said:

```
var b = CardView.Column((Person m) => m.Name);
```

or to supply type arguments to the generic method:

```
var b = CardView.Column<Person, string>(m => m.Name);
```